# Exiting a thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a program that pulls "work" from a database then dispatches it to workers.

I have a thread dedicated to doing some work in a loop.  The work it does comes from a database, and the call to get a message is blocking:

```
class MessageThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, db, worker_inbox, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MessageThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.db = db
        self.worker_inbox = worker_inbox  # this is a stdlib Queue.Queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            message = self.db.get()
            self.worker_inbox.put(message)
```

Without having to put some "flag" into the database, is there a nice way to stop this thread?  Currently I am setting the `daemon` flag on it, which kills it when the main thread exits, but I wondered if there was a nicer mechanism or way of designing this?

Comment: `db` looks like a `Queue`. How is `db` defined? Why not put a sentinel in `db`?

Comment: Sure, `db` is a queue, but the work is put there by various other processes so it is not a stdlib queue.  I don't want to put a sentinel in the DB -- that is mixing implementation with the data.  I'd rather learn if there is a standard way of architecting for this kind of scenario.

Comment: @coleifer Can you put a timeout on `.get`? If yes, then you could simply set a shared flag `ALIVE` and use `while ALIVE:` with timeout.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using an `Event` to signal when threads should shutdown.  The thing is, let's pretend that there is no ``.get(timeout=x)`` API.

Comment: @coleifer Well, I don't think there is anything else you can do without timeout and without sentinel in db.

Comment: @freakish -- Yes, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to design things.

Comment: I have little experience with threading, but why not add a second queue (a "command" queue, or instance) and have the thread check that queue periodically for a 'quit' command?

Answer (score 0):

Have your code look for a unique stop message in the queue. If it is normally passed some object, a string that says 'stop' is a nice quick self-documenting way to do it. When its time to terminate the worker, just drop 'stop' into the queue. This wakes the thread and tells it its done. You can use a Boolean, none or something that fits in the message you are passing.

```
while True:
    message = self.db.get()
    if instance(message, base string) and message == 'stop':
        break
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if db is a queue of messages then I would just put some "quit" fake message to this queue.
Here is some pseudo code how it might look.

```
class MessageThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, db, worker_inbox, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MessageThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.db = db
        self.worker_inbox = worker_inbox  # this is a stdlib Queue.Queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            message = self.db.get()
            if "quit" == message:
                return
            self.worker_inbox.put(message)
    def quit(self):
        self.db.put("quit")

 a = MessageThread()
 a.start()
 sleep(1.0)
 a.quit()
 a.join()
```